# When asset paths don't match up with the asset pipeline, should I edit paths or try and precompile fonts into a different directory?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, fonts, ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline

I am working on a project with a bootstrap theme and the font paths inside **toolkit.css** are pointing to `../fonts/`.

When rails precompiles my fonts in `/app/assets/fonts/` it puts them in `/public/assets` but the CSS file is pointing to `public/fonts`.

Here's a code snippet:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "toolkit-entypo";
  src: url("../fonts/toolkit-entypo.eot");
  src: url("../fonts/toolkit-entypo.eot?#iefix") format("eot"), 
url("../fonts/toolkit-entypo.woff2") format("woff2"), 
url("../fonts/toolkit-entypo.woff") format("woff"), 
url("../fonts/toolkit-entypo.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal; }
```

I can think of two options, but I believe they each have faults:

1. Edit the CSS file and change `../fonts/` to `../assets/`

   - CON: If I ever get a newer version of toolkit.css, I'll have to remake the changes
2. Try and figure out how to precompile *only* the fonts in `/app/assets/fonts/` into `/public/fonts/`.

   - CON: One may not even be able to precompile assets into a directory lower than `/public/assets/`

I understand that this question is opinion based since I am proposing two potential solutions, but perhaps someone in the world can point me in the right direction.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Right now, I'm reading into 5.5 Changing the assets Path: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#changing-the-assets-path. I think if I can tweak the location, just for the fonts, then perhaps I'll be out of the weeds.

Comment: I think the Rails way is to edit the css file and use `asset_path` helper. But you're right about the con.